# Create an async function within Flask using Python 3.5?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, python-3.5

I am attempting to update a Slack App for my company that will query our API, perform a few calculations, and spit out a nice report. The problem is that the report takes about 7-10 seconds to run and Slack only allows a 3000ms timeout on a slash command.

This isn't a huge problem though, because you can respond immediately with a message acknowledging the command and then when the report completes respond again.

The rest of our Slack app is written with a Flask backend and hosted on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, so we run Python 3.5.

The code I've [found](https://renzo.lucioni.xyz/serverless-slash-commands-with-python/) that demonstrates how to do what I want uses the Zappa library, which looks like it's for AWS's lamdba, uses a `@task` decorator to force a function to be asynchronous. Unfortunately, it doesn't run on less than Python 3.6.

Example code from the tutorial:

```
@task
def hello_there_task(response_url):
    sleep(5)

    data = {
        'response_type': 'in_channel',
        'text': 'You _are_ a bold one.',
    }

    requests.post(response_url, json=data)


@app.route('/hello-there', methods=['POST'])
def hello_there():
    if not is_request_valid(request):
        abort(400)

    hello_there_task(request.form['response_url'])

    return jsonify(
        response_type='in_channel',
        text='<https://youtu.be/frszEJb0aOo|General Kenobi!>',
    )
```

My question: How can I make the `hello_there_task` asynchronous in Python 3.5? It doesn't have to be a decorator, though it wouldn't hurt for future use.

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood from brief look at Zappa, a `@task` decorator doesn't make a function async, but is just an interface to Zappa's executor. In pure Python, [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) and [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) seem very similar to it.